# How to copy multiple columns to single column in excel using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I am new to python. I would like to copy multiple columns to single column in a excel using python.
And in that single column first heading and then value if the value is not present the that column should not copy.

Example Excel data:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three | Four |
| Five |  | Six | Seven |
| xyz | hjy |  | abc |

Excepted Result:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |  | Column A :One, Column B:Two, Column C:Three |
| Five |  | Six | Seven | Column A :Five, Column C:Six, Column D:Seven |
| xyz | hjy |  | abc | Column A :xyz, Column B:hjy, Column D:abc |

[Example and Expected result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOkZZ.png)

Kindly help to resolve the issue.
Thank you.

Comment: I have a Excel file and I want to copy the multiple columns data in to single column with (columns headings and values).

Comment: what is a data type for column E? is it a dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not quite clear what you expect to get, but with this you'll get something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df['col_E'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(f'{k}:{v}' for k,v in x.dropna().to_dict().items()),1)
df.to_excel('new_file.xlsx',index=False)
```

new_file.xlsx
[image]

**upd**

selecting columns to read from excel file:

```
cols = ['Column A', 'Column C', 'Column D']  # columns to read

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', usecols=cols)
#                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
df['col_E'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(f'{k}:{v}' for k,v in x.dropna().to_dict().items()),1)
df.to_excel('new_file.xlsx',index=False)
```

new_file.xlsx

[image]

Comment: Lets say in my current file only am having 6 columns and 4 rows(A->F and 1->4) In 7th column I would like to copy the headings and values of B->E columns in a single column.

Comment: This Script is working. Thank you. But I would like to copy only couple of columns not all columns. So, how to do that. Let say I have excel with 10 columns and in that I would like to copy 6 columns to a new column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two for loops, the outer one being for the rows and the inner one for the columns, and for each cell then check whether the cell.value!=null, if not you can add the value to a string and then when you reach the final element of the inner loop you can add the particular content to the respective last column.